# How to set redirect rules for S3?

Tags: url, amazon-s3, routes, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

My app will have several routes like:

```
myapp.com
myapp.com/
myapp.com/items
myapp.com/items/
myapp.com/items/23234
```

Of course tha last one have an id as the last segment. This id will change frequently.

I desire to translate the routes to something like that:

```
myapp.com --> myapp.com
myapp.com/ --> myapp.com
myapp.com/items --> myapp.com?route=%2Fitems
myapp.com/items/ --> myapp.com?route=%2Fitems
myapp.com/items/23234 --> myapp.com?route=%2Fitems%2F23234
```

How could I map the routes this way using S3 (or CloudFront)?

Comment: What is the use though? Query strings aren't useful with S3.

Comment: The reason Is that I'm hosting an Angular 7 PWA in S3. The routes like "myapp.com/items" just don't works at the first time the user opens the app or when it's updated since this routes are handled inside angular PWA and first is necessary to open the root route "myapp.com" to download the PWA. When "myapp.com/items" is opened for the first time the route is handled by S3 and not by Angular. S3 interprets this route as a object called "items" inside its directory structury.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to handle this route problem of Angular/S3. If the PWA root receive query parameters I can handle it inside the PWA.